# How to delete line if longer than XY?

Tags: sed

How can i delete a line if it is longer than e.g.: 2048 chars?

Comment: Do you insist on using sed? This is easy, for example in python. And no doubt even easier in perl. Though the question is not terribly well defined. Copy a file, removing all lines longer than 2048, or something else?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
sed '/^.\{2048\}./d' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: I get the error message `sed: 1: "/^.\{2048\}..*/d": RE error: invalid repetition count(s)` (Mac OS X)

Comment: @wedi you probably want to install the GNU version instead of the BSD version that ships with Mac.  This is easy with brew

Comment: The question says "if longer than XY (e.g., 2048 chars)". Then it must be > 2048 and not => 2048

Comment: @ajcg, It is > 2048. Notice that there's an extra period in the end of the regex to match the 2049th character.

Comment: @forcefsck and it wouldn't be better if you take it away "^" ? (with your command you are only removing lines that "start with XYZ", but if XYZ is in another part of the line then it does not delete it)

Comment: This is too slow to process large log files. Recommend the perl solution below.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a solution which deletes lines that has 2049 or more characters:

```
sed '/.\{2049\}/d' <file.in >file.out
```

The regular expression `.\{2049\}` would match any line that contains a substring of 2049 characters (another way of saying "at least 2049 characters").  The `d` command deletes them from the input, producing only shorter line on the output.

BSD `sed` (on e.g. macOS) can only handle repetition counts of up to 256 in the `\{...\}` operator (the value of `RE_DUP_MAX`; see `getconf RE_DUP_MAX` in the shell).  On these systems, you may instead use `awk`:

```
awk 'length <= 2048' <file.in >file.out
```

Mimicking the `sed` solution literally with `awk`:

```
awk 'length >= 2049 { next } { print }' <file.in >file.out
```

Note that any `awk` implementation is only guaranteed to be able to handle records of lengths up to `LINE_MAX` bytes (see `getconf LINE_MAX` in the shell), but may support longer ones.  On macOS, `LINE_MAX` is 2048.

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -lne "length < 2048 && print" infile > outfile
```

Comment: +1 The `-l` isn't needed, though.

Comment: Does not work for me. Perl v5.16.2. `Warning: Use of "length" without parentheses is ambiguous at -e line 1. Unterminated <> operator at -e line 1.`

Comment: You may try `length($_) > 2048 && print`. `length` is a shortcut for `length($_)` anyway.

Comment: Had to use ' instead of "

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work in Python.

```
of = open("orig")
nf = open("new",'w')
for line in of:         
    if len(line) < 2048:
        nf.write(line)
of.close()
nf.close()
```

Comment: Personally, @Faheem, I prefer your answer. The reason why is that it was very easy for me to turn it around into 'delete all lines smaller than x'. I don't use Python all the time, but when I do I always feel I should learn it well.

Comment: @ixtmixilix: Yes, using a full featured language like Python is pretty flexible. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If you love Python but also like using the CLI and not having to write and run a seperate script for this task, check out `pz`! : https://github.com/CZ-NIC/pz  It brings Python to shell pipes.  For this question the solution would be `cat input | pz 's if len(s) < 2048 else ""' > output`

Answer (score 1):

The above answers do not work for me on Mac OS X 10.9.5.

The following code does work:

`sed '/.\{2048\}/d'`.

Although not asked, but provided for reference, the reverse can be achieved the following code:

`sed '/.\{2048\}/!d'`.

Comment: lol, but `sed: 1: "/.\{2048\}/d": RE error: invalid repetition count(s)` (`Mac OS X, 10.10.4`)

Comment: Ah. I installed the GNU version instead of the BSD version that ships with Mac as @Freedom_Ben suggested above. But Kusalananda found the switch to enable extended regex. So you should go with his solution if you still have that problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

With gnu-sed, you may use the -r flag, to avoid typing the backslashes, and a comma, to define an open interval:

```
sed -r  "/.{2049,}/d" input.txt > output.txt
```

with:

- x{2049} meaning exactly 2049 xs
- x{2049,3072} meaning from 2049 to 3072 xs
- x{2049,} meaning at least 2049 xs
- x{,2049} meaning at most 2049 xs

For the intervals, to not match bigger patterns, you would need line anchors like

```
sed -r  "/^.{32,64}$/d" input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` solutions are all very slow when the line lengths become very long. This is the disadvantage of matching line length with regexes. (But of course the advantage is that `sed` is everywhere)

If you like the speed of the Perl solution, but prefer using Python, the `pz` CLI tool makes this really easy.  It brings Python to shell pipes.

With pz the solution would be:

```bsh
cat input | pz 's if len(s) < 2048 else ""' > output
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the row at each char by setting `FS` to nothing :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} NF <= 2048' file
```

test with :

```
perl -e 'print "z"x2048' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} NF <= 2048'
# This print

perl -e 'print "z"x2049' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} NF <= 2048'
# This not
```

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby:

```bsh
ruby -ne 'print if $_.size <= 2048' input.txt > output.txt
```

Or to edit in place and create a backup:

```bsh
ruby -i.bak -ne 'print if $_.size <= 2048' file.txt
```

Without a backup:

```bsh
ruby -i -ne 'print if $_.size <= 2048' file.txt
```

Note: `$_.size` includes the trailing newline, if any. You can use `$_.chomp.size` to ignore trailing newlines.

You could also check line size via a regex, like some of the other examples, but it will be slower:

```bsh
# slow
ruby -ne 'print if /.{2048}./' input.txt > output.txt
```