# How to remove lines shorter than XY?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I found a question about, how to remove lines longer then 2048 chars:

[How to delete line if longer than XY?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/how-to-delete-line-if-longer-than-xy)

**Q:** But how can I remove lines shorter then 4 chars? So remove lines that has 1 or 2 or 3 length in a file.

UPDATE: Thanks for the many GOOD answers, but I can only mark one as OK

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You could use `sed`.  The following would remove lines that are 3 characters long or smaller:

```
sed -r '/^.{,3}$/d' filename
```

In order to save the changes to the file in-place, supply the `-i` option.

If your version of `sed` doesn't support extended RE syntax, then you could write the same in BRE:

```
sed '/^.\{,3\}$/d' filename
```

which would work with all `sed` variants.

---

You could also use `awk`:

```
awk 'length($0)>3' filename
```

---

Using `perl`:

```
perl -lne 'length()>3 && print' filename
```

Comment: `sed '/^.\{,3\}$/d'` doesn't work with BSD sed: `sed: 1: "/^.\{,3\}$/d": RE error: invalid repetition count(s)`. The sed -r version is syntactically valid, but won't remove lines.

Answer (score 11):

Some more variations:

```
grep .... file
```

or

```
sed '/..../!d' file
```

or

```
sed -n 's/./&/4p' file
```

or

```
awk 'gsub(/./,"&")>3' file
```

or

```
awk 'length>3' file
```

or GNU awk:

```
awk 'NF>3' FS= file
```

Comment: Oh that grep .... is so elegant!

Answer (score 7):

Here is the Vim solution using Vim's Ex mode and the `global` command.

This is very similar to using `sed`, only that some special chars ('{', '}') need to be escaped.

```
:g/^.\{,3\}$/d
```

Using Vim's Very Magic Regex mode (\v), this escaping can be avoided.

```
:g/\v^.{,3}$/d
```

See also :help magic

```
Use of "\v" means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except
'0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning.  "very magic"
```

Also sometimes useful is to do the opposite with `vglobal`.

```
:v/\v^.{,3}$/d
```

would delete everything but lines till 3 chars.

Comment: Thanks. saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

to directly remove the lines you could:

```
sed -ri '/.{4}/!d' /path/to/file
```

Or BRE:

```
sed -i '/.\{4\}/!d' /path/to/file
```

If a line does not contain 4 or more characters it is deleted.

```
f=/path/to/file
cat <<GREP >"$f"
    $(grep -E ".{4}" "$f")
GREP
```

Doing the above in command-substitution subshell will ensure that `grep` gets a read descriptor on it before cat starts writing to it, but the `<<HEREDOC` will also ensure that the result remains streamed and does not cause argument length errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep`:

If you count leading spaces in line length:

```
grep -e '[^\ ]\{4,\}' file
```

If you don't count leading spaces in line leangth:

```
grep -e '[^\]\{4,\}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^.\?.\?.\?$/d' input.txt > output.txt
```