# Remove line of exactly n characters

Tags: text-processing

I have several huge .txt files and I need to remove a line if it is exactly 9 characters long. No more no less.

Is there a way to do this using awk / sed?

Comment: [How to remove lines shorter than XY?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123243) and [How to delete line if longer than XY?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9981)...

Comment: I saw those, but I need it to be exactly x length, not shorter than or longer than.

Comment: The solutions there require minor modifications to do what you want... I mean even someone who is not familiar with `sed`/`awk` should be able to change those commands to remove lines of a certain length.

Comment: Here's another one: [How to “grep” for line length *not* in a given range?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249224)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU `sed`'s extended regexes:

```
for file in ./*.txt; do
    sed -i -r '/^.{9}$/d' "${file}"
done
```

(Use `-E` instead of `-r` on FreeBSD/macOS (`-E` will also work in recent versions of GNU `sed`) and `-i ''` instead of `-i`)

As pointed out by [don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti), with GNU `sed` you don't need the loop:

```
sed -s -i -r '/^.{9}$/d' ./*.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`:

```
for f in ./*.txt; do
    awk 'length($0) != 9' "$f" >"destdir/$f"
done
```

With `sed`:

```
for f in ./*.txt; do
    sed '/^.\{9\}$/d' "$f" >"destdir/$f"
done
```

With `grep`:

```
for f in ./*.txt; do
    egrep -vx '.{9}' "$f" >"destdir/$f"
done
```

Comment: Note that `\{` was added to `grep` before `{` was added to `egrep`. Some `egrep` implementations (like Solaris `/bin/egrep`) still don't support it (as that would break backward compatibility while the introduction of `\{` in BRE didn't break backward compatibility). The modern and standard equivalent of `egrep` is `grep -E` (on Solaris, you need `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` or `command -p grep`).

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
grep -vE '^.{9}$' filename > new_filename
```

Switch the 9 to whatever characters needed.

```
       -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
       -E, --extended-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular  expression  (ERE,  see
          below).
```

`.` means any character, `{9}` means match this pattern 9 times.
`^` means start of line and `$` means end of line.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk length!=9 < in > out
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.txt
do
  egrep -v '^.........$' <"$i" >destdir/"$i"
done
```

Or, if you insist on using `sed` rather than `egrep`:

```
for i in *.txt
do
  sed '^.........$/d' <"$i" >destdir/"$i"
done
```

To remove lines that are 235 characters long:

```
X=""
for i in `seq 1 235`
do
  X="$X."
done

for i in *.txt
do
  egrep -v '^'"$X"'$' <"$i" >destdir/"$i"
done
```

Simplicity itself!

Comment: What if the next guy needs to remove lines that are 235 chars long ?

Comment: @don_crissti Added to answer.

Comment: You call that "simplicity" ? OK...

Comment: @don_crissti Admittedly, the '{}' syntax for regular expressions is a cleaner way to do it. I didn't know sed supported it until now, tbh.