# Only keep lines containing x or less number of numbers. TXT file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, perl, text

I found a similar question:

- [How to delete line if longer than XY?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/how-to-delete-line-if-longer-than-xy)

But in this case I want to check not the total length, but the number of digits in the line.  For example, out of this input:

```
cdc85e24-b9e9-8802-080a-b84479e1ae82  
ekodeveloper0  
1795475824.1129747.1472396049615.ref  
1795475824.1129747.1472396049615  
967175540.1194446.1472407271491  
wangxiuyan552  
jveazey  
xoloki  
whelee  
matthauck  
patel3.anirudh  
mischa.salle
```

How can I delete all the lines with more than N digits in them?

Comment: Post your desired output as well as your input please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to only keep lines having X or *more* numbers.  Here is an example of that where X is 13:

```
sed -n 's/[0-9]/&/13p' input.txt > output.txt
```

However, you can modify this to do the reverse.  Here is a command that will only keep lines having **fewer than 13** numbers:

```
sed -n -e 's/[0-9]/&/13;t' -e 'p' input.txt > output.txt
```

---

### Explanation - print only lines with 13+ numbers

```
sed -n 's/[0-9]/&/13p' input.txt > output.txt
```

The `&` symbol in replacement text means "everything that was matched."

The number flag on the `s` command (after the `/find/replace/` part) means only replace that instance of the search pattern.

The `p` flag on the `s` command means "print if a substitution was made."

The `-n` switch, of course, is to suppress Sed's default "print" action.

### Explanation - print only lines with <13 numbers

```
sed -n -e 's/[0-9]/&/13;t' -e 'p' input.txt > output.txt
```

The `-e` switch is "execute"; it just passes a command.  We need it here since we are passing more than one.

The `t` command skips the remaining commands if the last `s` command performed a substitution.

The `p` command prints.

Comment: Thanks. Trying it out right now. I forgot to mention that the thing I linked has nothing to do with this current request.

Comment: @silc, okay; I saw the similarity anyway.  Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark at the left if it solved your question.

Comment: Where do I execute this in? "sed" unrecognized command in cmd.exe and perl command line.

Comment: @silc, any shell.  Bash, ksh, zsh, dash, any of them should work just fine.  Not sure I get the question; you tagged this post "shell script."

Comment: I wasn't sure which program it could be done in. I'm trying to make it work in shell now. "The term "sed" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function script file or operable program. Check spelling or path and try again. At line:1 char: 4

Comment: AWESOME DUDE!! Got it working in bash!! Big triple thanks for helping me out man!!!

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged your question `perl`, once way to do it in perl would be to make use of the fact that perl's `tr` returns a count of the number of characters replaced; so for example (taking `N = 13`) you could do

```
perl -ne 'print unless tr/[0-9]/[0-9]/ > 13' file
ekodeveloper0
wangxiuyan552
jveazey
xoloki
whelee
matthauck
patel3.anirudh
mischa.salle
```

A possibly more conventional way would be to evaluate the regex match in a scalar context to get a count

```
perl -ne '$c = () = /\d/g; print unless $c > 13' file
```

See for example [Is there a Perl shortcut to count the number of matches in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1849356/4440445)